# SmartyStreets: Adjust location of Verified tick in Form with Conditional Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, smartystreets

I'm using SmartyStreets and have a bunch of conditional fields that modify the DOM. I'm also using a responsive design that affects the layout. The issue I have is the verified tick doesn't always retrigger and remap to the correct field after another field becomes visible on the form.

This especially seems to be an issue based on the screen size of the window on load. Changing the windowsize does fix the issue.

Is there a way I can force a re-trigger of SmartyStreets to re-position the Verified tick.

Comment: You can see an example of this here: https://jsfiddle.net/rmlumley/8m2n1mnj/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/smartystreets/mnh18fx1/) of modal usage with the plugin. Deactivating (when the form is hidden) and reactivating (when the form is shown) an address based off the id given during mapping and then calling `$(window).resize()` will ensure that the checkmark is hidden when the form is hidden and shown when the form is shown.

I was able to add in `$(window).resize()` after your calls to deactivate and activate and got it to work properly. [Here is the updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8m2n1mnj/4/).